# Rstudio Rtools error?? 'Renviron contains invalid lines'

Tags: r

I use Rstudio.

I got an error while using Rstudio.
It's the same error as in the attached image.
I uninstalled Rtools, Rstudio and R and then reinstalled them all, but it doesn't change.
This error occurs at startup and the screen goes white and stops.
Do you know how to solve this problem?

devtools::find_rtools() is now True.
This error occurs whether Rtools is present in the path or not.
It also occurs in R-GUI.
R version 4.0.3

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have a .Renviron file with some invalid characters in it. Does `readLines(path.expand("~/.Renviron"))` return anything? If you don't need anything in that file, you can probably delete it.

Comment: "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin",It's back.
Renviron was not in the folder.

Comment: What do you mean "it's back"? If that path was returns by the `readLines` command, then the file exists. If you are on windows, it may hide files with names that start with a period by default. (Usually those are hidden files). You can use `unlink(path.expand("~/.Renviron"))` to delete it. Not sure why that PATH value would have wound up in an .Renviron file.

Comment: I ran unlink and it successfully resolved the error. Thank you MrFlick !

Comment: unlink really works for me as well!